# Formating in columns with printf

Tags: c

Hi guys I am new to programming. Whenever I try to format into columns with printf I get some really strange behavior.

```
for (int i = 0; i< count; i++) {
       printf("%s %-20s %c\n",studentData[i].firstName, studentData[i].lastName,       studentData[i].letterGrade);
    }
```

Im trying to get this output

```
John Jones &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; A

Bob Smith &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C 

Sam Johnson &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;B

etc... instead I get

John Jones&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A

Bob Smith&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C

Sam Johnson &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;B
```

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    struct studendt {
        char firstName[10];
        char lastName[10];
        char letterGrade;
    } studentData[16] = {
        { "John", "Jones"  , 'A'},
        { "Bob" , "Smith"  , 'C'},
        { "Sam" , "Johnson", 'B'}
    };
    int count = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i< count; i++) {
        char name[20];//firstName_len(X-1) + lastName_len(X-1) + 1(' ') + 1(NUL) = 2X
        snprintf(name, sizeof name, "%s %s", 
            studentData[i].firstName, studentData[i].lastName);
        printf("%-20s %c\n", name, studentData[i].letterGrade);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1 What on earth is a 18.5k rep user doing submitting code dumps with no explanation?

Comment: seeking explanation of this code is to diminish the dignity of the person.